# Mass Scanning and Renaming of File Names

Tags: ruby, itunes, finder, file-rename

I have searched all over StackOverflow and other parts of the internet and so far I have found nothing that can help solve my problem.

My problem is that in iTunes I have about 220 songs that are listed like "Artist Name - Song Name" (ex. "Modest Mouse - Dramamine") and I am wondering if there is any way that I can write a Ruby script that would change those to listing properly in iTunes with the word(s) after the hyphen ("Dramamine") becoming the song title and the word(s) before the hyphen ("Modest Mouse") becoming the artist.

Also, if there are any programs that could accomplish the same goal it would be appreciated if someone could share a link, however, if anyone could point me to somewhere where I can learn how to mass scan and make changes to filenames in Ruby then put those song changes into songs that iTunes can read and display then that would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are many examples of recursive directory scanning and MP3 libraries (like ruby-mp3info, taglib-ruby, etc). What specifically are you having an issue with?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Regex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) and [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) Ruby Libraries, as well as [Dir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html). They give you the tools for the job.

For example,

```
Dir["path/to/your/music/*.m4a"].each do |filename|
  m = File.basename(filename).match(/(.+)-(.+)/)
  artist = m[1].strip # remove leading and trailing blanks
  song = m[2].strip
  new_filename = song + ' - ' + artist
  File.rename(filename, "path/to/your/music/#{new_filename}.m4a"
|end|
```

There are other tricks, for instance you can use back-ticks (`, not ') to do file renaming by replacing the last line in the block with:

```
`mv #{filename} path/to/your/music/#{new_filename}.m4a`
```

This will run the mv command in the Unix shell.

Good luck tinkering around! Nothing beats learning by trial and error!